# Get.to() with conditional after clicked onPressed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have Get.to() that will show webview after i clicked it

```
                       onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                              Timer(
                                Duration(milliseconds: 350),
                                () => {
                                  Get.to(
                                    WebviewService(
                                      urlName: action.name!,
                                      urlPath: action.link!,
                                    ),
                                    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
                                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                  )
                                },
                              );
                            },
```

but recently I want to add another conditional route, example: when I clicked on few exact item it will show the page_view.dart that consists native view instead of webview, and when I click on another item that had no view page it will show the webview. just like this:

```
if(x == page_view){
 show page_view()
}else{
 WebviewService(
  urlName: action.name!,
  urlPath: action.link!,
  ),
}
```

How to make that conditional Get.to()

Comment: What do you mean under 'click on another item that no view page'?

Comment: sorry, im already fixed the spelling

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you want to make navigation that depend on the conditions.
But unfortunately you can't add conditions in `GO.to` you need to perform condition checking before using of the `GO.to` and pass exact route where do you want to navigate or you can make the condition in the [GoRouter](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/GoRouter-class.html) that you initialized in your app before.

You can think about the `GO.to` as a trigger that triggers the navigation with parameters that you pass in.